# How to rename a file with Python?

Tags: python, copy, rename

I am trying to change the name of file using Python but the name does not change.

The program has to take a photo, save it, copy it to a server, change the name of copied photo and change the name of original photo.
So, first of all I define a variable which is going to be a exact date and time. After that, I take a photo and save it like imagen.jpg
Following, I copy imagen.jpg to other path (server path), and try change its name to the variable which I defined before. But the name does not change and the file is removed.

After that I change  the name of original photo with the same function and the name is changed....I don't know why the copied photo doesn't change its name.

Here's the code:

```
import shutil
import picamera
import os
fecha = time.strftime("%c")  # En esta variable se guarda la fecha actual y la hora para renombrar la foto guardada          
camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/imagen.jpg')
print("Capturando foto")
time.sleep(5)
print("Copiando foto al servidor")
shutil.copy("/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/imagen.jpg", "/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos")
time.sleep(1)
os.listdir("/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos")
os.rename ("/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/imagen.jpg", fecha)
print("Cambiando nombre al archivo")
os.rename ("/home/pi/Desktop/RaspAlarm/imagen.jpg", fecha)
time.sleep(1)
print("Foto guardada")
```

Could you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your destination name is wrong. You are basically calling:

```
os.rename("/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/imagen.jpg", "Mon May  8 16:15:07 2017")
```

while what you want looks more like

```
os.rename("/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/imagen.jpg", "/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/Mon May  8 16:15:07 2017.jpg")
```

Check the documentation for [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename)

Comment: Yes I know. But when I try to hange the name of original photo the name is changed successfully using the same function. Why? Or, how can I add the .jpg extension like you said before?

Comment: @SergioMuñoz to add an extension you can use [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) or just `path + fecha + '.jpg'` if you're dealing with jpegs only. And yes, check out the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) library.

Comment: Ok! I will try this. But is rare that in the original photo the name is changed well

Answer (score 1):

At first your destination is wrong! you should write all the path.
Then you should remove spaces in fecha variable :

```
fecha = fecha.replace(' ', '')
os.rename("/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/imagen.jpg", "/var/www/html/RaspAlarm/Fotos/{}.jpg".format(fecha))
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But Why the original photo changes his names well? If I am using the same function

Comment: I dont think so, os.remove work exactly like mv command in Linux if you put destination as a word not as a path it will move the file to the function's directory. So I think maybe it works for you because the function is in the same directory as the original photo!